# i want to separate single row amd append as new rows with same index and appending twi required column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Index':['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'In': ['3-Dec-21', '19-Dec-21', '20-Marc-21', '20-Apr-21', '1-Jan-21'],
        'Out': ['5-Feb-22', '6-May-22', '25-Jun-22', '15-Jun-22', '8-Mar-22'],           
      'Restricted dates': ['10-Jan-22', '10-Mar-22', '10-Jan-22', '10-Mar-22', '9-Apr-22'],
                  'Previous date':['9-Jan-22', '9-Mar-22', '9-Jan-22', '9-Mar-22', '8-Apr-22'],
                  'Next date':['11-Jan-22', '11-Mar-22', '11-Jan-22', '11-Mar-22', '10-Apr-22']})
    Index   In      Out     Restricted dates    Previous date   Next date
0   A   *3-Dec-21*  **5-Feb-22**    10-Jan-22       *9-Jan-22*          **11-Jan-22**
1   B   19-Dec-21   6-May-22    10-Mar-22       9-Mar-22            11-Mar-22
2   C   20-Marc-21  25-Jun-22   10-Jan-22       9-Jan-22            11-Jan-22
3   D   20-Apr-21   15-Jun-22   10-Mar-22       9-Mar-22            11-Mar-22
4   E   1-Jan-21    8-Mar-22    9-Apr-22        8-Apr-22            10-Apr-22
```

I want to add row which will took 'In' column , 'Previous date' columns as separate df
and will append 'next date' rows in 'In'column and 'Out' column in 'previous date'column

```
Index   In      intermediate
A   03-Dec-21   09-Jan-22
A   11-Jan-22   05-Feb-22
B   19-Dec-21   9-Mar-22
B   11-Mar-22   06-May-22
C   20-Mar-21   09-Jan-22
C   11-Jan-22   25-Jun-22
D   20-Apr-21   09-Mar-22
D   11-Mar-22   15-Jun-22
E   01-Jan-21   08-Apr-22
E   10-Apr-22   08-Mar-22
```

Comment: for the first row for `B` why is it 10th Mar and not 9th Mar, since 9th Mar is the value in the Previous date column

Comment: My bad.it is 9th march only.

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.select_columns('Index', 'In', 'Previous date', 'Out', 'Next date')
.pivot_longer(index = 'Index', 
              names_to = ['In', 'Intermediate'], 
              names_pattern = ('In|Next date', 'Previous date|Out'), 
              sort_by_appearance = True)

  Index          In Intermediate
0     A    3-Dec-21     9-Jan-22
1     A   11-Jan-22     5-Feb-22
2     B   19-Dec-21     9-Mar-22
3     B   11-Mar-22     6-May-22
4     C  20-Marc-21     9-Jan-22
5     C   11-Jan-22    25-Jun-22
6     D   20-Apr-21     9-Mar-22
7     D   11-Mar-22    15-Jun-22
8     E    1-Jan-21     8-Apr-22
9     E   10-Apr-22     8-Mar-22
```

The function pairs the patterns in `names_pattern` with `names_to` to get the output. However, it works on a first come first serve basis, hence the need to rearrange the column positions. With the rearrangement, `In` will be paired with `Previous date` (because that is the first column that `In` will see) while in the next iteration `Out` will be combined with `Next date`.

[pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) offers convenience and efficiency; however, you can do this all within Pandas and avoid having to load another library:

```py
temp = df.set_index('Index')
columns = ['In', 'intermediate']
top = temp.loc[:, ['In' ,'Previous date']].set_axis(columns, axis = 1)
bottom = temp.loc[:, ['Next date', 'Out']].set_axis(columns, axis = 1)

pd.concat([top, bottom]).sort_index().reset_index()

  Index          In intermediate
0     A    3-Dec-21     9-Jan-22
1     A   11-Jan-22     5-Feb-22
2     B   19-Dec-21     9-Mar-22
3     B   11-Mar-22     6-May-22
4     C  20-Marc-21     9-Jan-22
5     C   11-Jan-22    25-Jun-22
6     D   20-Apr-21     9-Mar-22
7     D   11-Mar-22    15-Jun-22
8     E    1-Jan-21     8-Apr-22
9     E   10-Apr-22     8-Mar-22
```

Comment: Thank you.it works for me.can u tell me if i want to loop on different columns.Like i have multiple columns starting Previous date1,previous date2,previous date3.... and also next date1,next date2,next date3......can we apply same rule without mentioning specific columns name.

Comment: The names pattern are regexes so it should work. Give it a go let's see